# Custom checkbox in Opencart admin page is not checked

Tags: php, html, checkbox, opencart

I'm trying to implement a custom feature in Opencart, so I need to add a couple of checkboxes in the backend (Admin Page). I've already done that and the settings I want are correctly being written into the database and cause exactly the result I want.

The problem I have now, is that when I'm going to change again these settings (select another checkbox), the previous status is not displayed (no matter what I've checked before, both checkboxes are shown empty).

Because I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, does anybody know where exactly?

Comment: In the future it would be nice if You could share your code with us so that we could identify the exact problem. Now we only could guess where the problem could be. Luckily for you, first answer pointed it out. But with such *abstract* question you risk it will be closed as Off Topic.

Comment: Because of Opencart's complex structure (a simple checkbox may involve several changes to a lot of files) I preferred to provide information about the nature of the problem (since the main functionality was just as expected). You're right, I was quite lucky since an experienced programmer immediately realized where the bug was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you checking to see if the setting has been set?
For instance:

Controller file:

```
if (isset($this->request->post['custom_setting'])) {
    $this->data['custom_setting'] = $this->request->post['custom_setting'];
} else {
    $this->data['custom_setting'] = $this->config->get('custom_setting');       
}
```

.tpl file:

```
<?php if ($custom_setting) { ?>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked">My Setting</option>
<?php } else { ?>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1">My Setting</option>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot because actually you helped me find the possible bug. I didn't make the check in the controller file (I added it though) but in .tpl I did. The code is the following:
  
`<?php if (in_array($config_customer_group_id,$config_customer_group_display)) { ?>
   <input type="checkbox" name="config_customer_group_display[]" value="<?php echo $customer_group['customer_group_id']; ?>" checked="checked" />
`
and the error log complains about not giving an array as 2nd argument.

Comment: Solved! Thanks a lot, you gave me the right direction :)